# Get data from mongodb with button in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to get data from a mongo database with a button click like this, using meteor:

html:

```
<body>
{{> getData}}

{{> getResult}}
</body>

<template name="getData">
<form class="getDataForm">
    <button class="getBtn">Search</button>
</form>
</template>

<template name="getResult">
<h1>Search result!</h1>

<ul>
{{#each foundUsers}}
    <li>{{firstname}}</li>
    <li>{{last}}</li>
    <li>{{picture}}</li>
    <li>{{phone}}</li>
    <li>{{information}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

js:

```
Users = new Meteor.Collection("user");

if (Meteor.isClient)
{
Template.getResult.events(
{
    'click .getBtn' : function ()
    {
        return Users.find();
    }
});
}
```

When I click this search button, nothing shows. The getResult list is not populated with the data that I do have in my database. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
Users = new Meteor.Collection("user");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.getData.events({
    'click .getBtn': function() {
      Session.set('userSearch', {});
    }
  });

  Template.getResults.foundUsers = function() {
    var userSearch = Session.get('userSearch');
    return userSearch && Users.find(userSearch);
  };
}
```

However I would advise you to use Meteor's built-in secure [Accounts API](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) if your users will be logging in to your website.